# Http request refused on Windows environment but not on OSX (mac)

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, npm, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a React web app with npm for the first time. I'm done with the development and now putting the built package on the web server (bluehost).
All is working well on my Mac: the web app allows getting data from mySQL via php, and posting back to the database.
But when I try the same app (on the same URL, same server, script, same everything...) on my Windows machine, I get an error on the first http request used for authentication.

*OPTION http://example.com/script.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*

First I thought this was a browser issue.
But I don't get the error on Chrome on my mac but do on Chrome on my Windows, as well as FireFox.
Again, I do not get this error when I test the app on my mac.

Could anybody please give me some direction to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a local server configuration issue most certainly

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Kisaragi! But the app is uploaded on a remote web server.

Comment: `But when I try the same app (on the same URL, same server, script, same everything...) on my Windows machine, I get an error on the first http request used for authentication.` You'll need to provide more information in your question, as well as clarify the actual environment for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Are you saying you cant access a remote website from ANY windows machine?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear @Kisaragi :(

Comment: Sorry for not being clear @Kisaragi :( I haven't tried with other windows and mac machines, and I will. Though, currently, all files are uploaded on a web host. Database, php files, and the web app package are on the same domain. But it's behaving differently on those two machines. I will test and update. Thank you!